# How to extrude rounded and smooth?

Tags: extrude

I have a following problem: I have a sphere and I want to extrude particles out of it like so:

[image: extruding in Blender]

But I want the extrusion to be rounded like in this picture: [image: Rounded extrusion]

What kind of settings do I miss please?

Comment: I dont know where that lower image comes from but I guess he is using subsurface modifier (press Strg+2)

Comment: I think this is it. But when I use it it applies on my whole object.  How to apply it only on my extruded one?

Comment: W -> Smooth Subdivide? Isnt quite the same but I think it will do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply a subsurf to part of an object, but you can control the way it subdivides.  Consider this object

[image]

If I apply the subsurf I get

[image]

It solves your problem by rounding, but it rounds where you don't want it to. There are several ways to fix this, depending on your need.  Here are a couple.

You can bevel edges and control how the rounding happens, perhaps making it less obvious

- Select edges you want to control
  [image]
- Enter CTRL-B. The cursor will change.  Moving it controls the width of the bevel. Rotating the scroll wheel controls the number of steps[image]

You can use the bevel modifier to accomplish the same thing but with more control.

You can create edge loops.  Consider the base of the extrusions. Enter CTRL-R. Place your cursor near the base of it until a red line appears around the extrusion
[image]

Left-Click and then move the line where you want it[image]

Left-Click again.

My example would require a lot of edge loops or a lot of bevels. Here's a version with all of the edge loops selected.[image]